# Internal Error Occurred When Creating RunSpace

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I have an app which allows user's to update other user's out of office message on Exchange via a simple web interface.

My initial attempt at creating this used using `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices` to connect to Exchange services, but I had to abandon this (even though it did work) due to the permissions required on the system account (an account updating OOF messages via `EWS` requires **FULL** mailbox permissions).

So to overcome this, I created the following class, which uses `PowerShell` remoting to achieve the same thing:

```
public class ExchangeShell
{
    private Runspace MyRunSpace;
    private PowerShell MyPowerShell;
    private Uri ExchangeServer;

    public ExchangeShell()
    {
        var exchangeserverurl = new Uri("http://EXCHANGESERVER/PowerShell");
        var psCredential = GetCredentials();
        var connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(exchangeserverurl, "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", psCredential);

        try
        {
            MyRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Email.Send($"Unable to connect \n\n Error: {ex.Message} ");
            Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);
        }
    }

    public OofSettings GetOofSettings(string email)
    {
        using (MyRunSpace)
        {
            MyRunSpace.Open();

            using (var powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                powerShell.Runspace = MyRunSpace;

                var command = new PSCommand();

                command.AddCommand("Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration");
                command.AddParameter("Identity", email);

                powerShell.Commands = command;

                var result = powerShell.Invoke();

                var oofSetting = new OofSettings();

                oofSetting.State = (OofState)Enum.Parse(typeof(OofState), result[0].Properties["AutoReplyState"].Value.ToString());
                oofSetting.Duration = new TimeWindow((DateTime)result[0].Properties["StartTime"].Value, (DateTime)result[0].Properties["EndTime"].Value);
                oofSetting.ExternalAudience = (OofExternalAudience)Enum.Parse(typeof(OofExternalAudience), result[0].Properties["ExternalAudience"].Value.ToString());
                oofSetting.InternalReply = result[0].Properties["InternalMessage"].Value.ToString();
                oofSetting.ExternalReply = result[0].Properties["ExternalMessage"].Value.ToString();

                return oofSetting;
            }
        }
    }

    private PSCredential GetCredentials()
    {
        var secureString = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in @"PASSWORD")
        {
            secureString.AppendChar(c);
        }
        return new PSCredential("SERVICEACCOUNT", secureString);
    }
}
```

This also works when run locally on my machine or as an EXE on the server.

However, when I host this over IIS I am seeing an error on this line:

```
MyRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
```

> An internal error occurred.

This is not a very helpful error message and I am not sure how I can go about debugging this. Does anyone have any suggestions on this?

---

**Update**

I attached a tracer in `web.config` and here is some trace information after selecting a user to retrieve their out of office details:

```
Category      Message                  From First(s)     From Last(s)
aspx.page     Begin PreInit   
aspx.page     End PreInit              0.000025          0.000025 
aspx.page     Begin Init               0.000035          0.000009 
aspx.page     End Init                 0.000057          0.000022 
aspx.page     Begin InitComplete       0.000065          0.000008 
aspx.page     End InitComplete         0.000073          0.000008 
aspx.page     Begin PreLoad            0.000081          0.000008 
aspx.page     End PreLoad              0.000093          0.000012 
aspx.page     Begin Load               0.000101          0.000008
```

But I really don't know what to make of this information - it doesn't seem to reveal much about what is actually going on between the `runspace` and the server..

**Stack Trace:**

> at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.Client.WSManClientSessionTransportManager.Initialize(Uri connectionUri, WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
>      at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.Client.WSManClientSessionTransportManager..ctor(Guid runspacePoolInstanceId, WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo, PSRemotingCryptoHelper cryptoHelper)
>      at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.ClientRemoteSessionDSHandlerImpl..ctor(ClientRemoteSession session, PSRemotingCryptoHelper cryptoHelper, RunspaceConnectionInfo connectionInfo, URIDirectionReported uriRedirectionHandler)
>      at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.ClientRemoteSessionImpl..ctor(RemoteRunspacePoolInternal rsPool, URIDirectionReported uriRedirectionHandler)
>      at System.Management.Automation.Internal.ClientRunspacePoolDataStructureHandler..ctor(RemoteRunspacePoolInternal clientRunspacePool, TypeTable typeTable)
>      at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Internal.RemoteRunspacePoolInternal..ctor(Int32 minRunspaces, Int32 maxRunspaces, TypeTable typeTable, PSHost host, PSPrimitiveDictionary applicationArguments, RunspaceConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
>      at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspacePool..ctor(Int32 minRunspaces, Int32 maxRunspaces, TypeTable typeTable, PSHost host, PSPrimitiveDictionary applicationArguments, RunspaceConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
>      at System.Management.Automation.RemoteRunspace..ctor(TypeTable typeTable, RunspaceConnectionInfo connectionInfo, PSHost host, PSPrimitiveDictionary applicationArguments)
>      at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(RunspaceConnectionInfo connectionInfo, PSHost host, TypeTable typeTable, PSPrimitiveDictionary applicationArguments)
>      at SetOutOfOffice.ExchangeShell..ctor()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was being caused because I had the wrong version of PowerShell installed on the server.

It is a shame that the `Internal Error` message does not mention this, but probably a good one to check when this error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to debug you should be able to use tracing in .NET or just attach the debugger

A common issue is failing certificate checks so you might want to try to bypass those eg

connectionInfo.SkipCACheck = true;
  connectionInfo.SkipCNCheck = true;
  connectionInfo.MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 4;

Comment: Thanks for your answer Glen, I tried skipping those `connectionInfo` checks but without success. After checking `trace.axd` I really can't see any useful information (although maybe I'm not reading it right) - I posted some in my question